# MaskRCNN.train gives 'list index out of range'

Tags: object-detection, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation, faster-rcnn

I have been trying to use MaskRCNN with a Resnet backbone on the [DeepFashion2](https://github.com/switchablenorms/DeepFashion2) Dataset for instance segmentation. The custom configurations are as follows:

```
class ClothDataset(utils.Dataset):

    # load_dataset function is used to load the train and test dataset
    def load_dataset(self, dataset_dir):
        print("Inside Load Dataset")
        categories = ["short sleeve top", "long sleeve top", "short sleeve outwear", "long sleeve outwear", "vest", "sling", 
                      "shorts", "trousers", "skirt", "short sleeve dress", "long sleeve dress", "vest dress", "sling dress"]
        for index, category in enumerate(categories):
            self.add_class("fashion", index+1, category.lower())

        images_dir = dataset_dir + '/image/'
        annotations_dir = dataset_dir + '/annos/'

        for filename in listdir(images_dir):

            image_id = filename[:-4]
            
            # img_path and ann_path variables are defined
            img_path = images_dir + filename
            ann_path = annotations_dir + image_id + '.json'
            
            # using add_image function we pass image_id, image_path and ann_path so that the current
            # image is added to the dataset for training
            self.add_image('fashion', image_id=image_id, path=img_path, annotation=ann_path)

    
    # function used to extract bouding boxes from annotated files
    def extract_boxes(self, filename):
        print("Inside Extract Boxes")
        boxes = list()
        # Implementation for JSON annotations
        annotation_file = json.load(open(filename))
        for item in annotation_file.keys():
            if item != "source" and item != "pair_id":
                name = annotation_file[item]['category_name'].lower()
                coors = annotation_file[item]['bounding_box']
                coors.append(name)
                boxes.append(coors)
              
        # Extracting width and height of the image
        image_path = filename.replace("annos", "image").replace("json", "jpg")
        image = skimage.io.imread(image_path)
        height, width = image.shape[:2]
        
        return boxes, width, height
    

    # returns a boolean mask with following dimensions width * height * instances        
    def load_mask(self, image_id):
        print("Inside Load Mask")
        info = self.image_info[image_id]
        path = info['annotation']
        boxes, w, h = self.extract_boxes(path)
        masks = np.zeros([h, w, len(boxes)], dtype='uint8')
        class_ids = list()
        for i in range(len(boxes)):
            box = boxes[i]
            masks[box[1]:box[3], box[0]:box[2], i] = self.class_names.index(box[4])
            class_ids.append(self.class_names.index(boxes[i][4]))
          
        return masks, np.asarray(class_ids, dtype='int32')
    
    # this functions takes the image_id and returns the path of the image
    def image_reference(self, image_id):
        info = self.image_info[image_id]
        return info['path']


class ClothConfig(Config):
    # name of the configuration
    NAME = "fashion_config"
    
    GPU_COUNT = 1
    IMAGES_PER_GPU = 4
    STEPS_PER_EPOCH = 20
    
    # Number of Classes
    NUM_CLASSES = 1 + 13

    # Image Dimensions
    IMAGE_MIN_DIM = HEIGHT_TARGET
    IMAGE_MAX_DIM = WIDTH_TARGET
    IMAGE_SHAPE = [HEIGHT_TARGET, WIDTH_TARGET, 3]
    IMAGE_RESIZE_MODE = 'square'
    BACKBONE = 'resnet50'
    
    TRAIN_BN = True
    
    # Learning Rate
    LEARNING_RATE = 0.004
    WEIGHT_DECAY = 0.0
    LR_SCHEDULE = True
    
    # Dataloader Queue Size (was set to 100 but resulted in OOM error)
    MAX_QUEUE_SIZE = 10
    
    # Cache Items
    CACHE = True
    
    # Debug mode will disable model checkpoints
    DEBUG = False
    
    # Do not use multithreading as this slows down the dataloader!
    WORKERS = 0
    
    # Losses
    LOSS_WEIGHTS = {
        'rpn_class_loss': 1.0,    # is the class of the bbox correct? / RPN anchor classifier loss (Forground/Background)
        'rpn_bbox_loss': 1.0,     # is the size of the bbox correct? / RPN bounding box loss graph (bbox of generic object)
        'mrcnn_class_loss': 1.0,  # loss for the classifier head of Mask R-CNN (Background / specific class)
        'mrcnn_bbox_loss': 1.0,   # is the size of the bounding box correct or not? / loss for Mask R-CNN bounding box refinement
        'mrcnn_mask_loss': 1.0,   # is the class correct? is the pixel correctly assign to the class? / mask binary cross-entropy loss for the masks head
    }
    
    # Training Structure
    FPN_CLASSIF_FC_LAYERS_SIZE = 1024
    RPN_ANCHOR_SCALES = (32, 64, 128, 256, 512)
```

However, I get a 'list index out of range' error on calling model.train(..) and from the error stack I can't seem to figure out where exactly the issue is. Attaching the error logs below,

[image]
[image]

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

I've narrowed down the issue to a possible Tensorflow version incompatibility. Though I don't have all the specifics, it seems the problem might be related to this.

To provide more context, I was working with [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com) kernels to run the model. Initially, I was modifying an [existing notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/code/hmendonca/mask-rcnn-and-coco-transfer-learning-lb-0-155) in an attempt to reuse the original environment. That's when I encountered the error logs mentioned earlier. As an alternative, I tried using [another notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/code/markwijkhuizen/sartorius-mask-rcnn-efficientnetv2-train-2h/notebook) with a different, more up-to-date pinned environment, and interestingly, the same model worked(snapshot attached).

[image: MaskRCNN Running]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).